# How can we make a movable sentence?

Tags: java, swing

for example I want to have a sentence like "System" in my main frame which can move from left side of the frame to the right side of the frame or up to the down.how can I do it??

Comment: You are not very clear.  Could we please have more detail?

Comment: While I think I understand what you're asking, something tells me it won't be the answer for whatever problem you have. Please elaborate if possible.

Comment: Given that of your last 15 postings you have yet to "accept" a single answer I don't think its appropriate that we continue to help when you don't appreciate the efforts we make.

Comment: Yet another missive from the Johanna-bot...

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you are trying to implement a sliding text. You may use the `Timer` class to set your label's(or whatever the component is) position. Every time the Timer ticks, you may increment the position or decrement it, the rest is up to your choice.

And I also must say, that you should be more clear when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for a mqrquee component in Swing.
[Here](http://forums.sureshkumar.net/java-technologies/21556-java-swing-program-marquee-text.html) is a simple3 example of how to rite one in swing.